# How do I know if I need AMD-64.deb or x86_64.rpm?

Tags: command-line, cpu

Is there a simple command (like `uname -r` to know my kernel version) to know if I need to download a AMD-64.deb package or a x86_64.rpm one ?

For example, for downloading printer drivers, I need to decide which one to take.

Sorry, if this is a dupe, I've seen many questions around this matter, but didn't find how to know what is my processor.

Comment: Ubuntu is a Debian clone. Uses packages_amd64 **.deb** .

Comment: Sorry for the dupe. @KnudLarsen, thanks but `uname -m` returned `x86_64` so I shouldn't consider this and dowload .deb instead...

Comment: .deb is for debian based linux'es, as Ubuntu. ..rpm's are for Red Hat / Fedora based systems